# How to create zero thickness internal walls in a given mesh in OpenFOAM?

Tags: openfoam

I know using `topoSet` and `subsetMesh` along the lines of the `mesh/moveDynamicMesh/simpleHarmonicMotion` tutorial, one can cut holes into a mesh and obtain new patches. How can something similar be achieved with a vanishing hole, i.e. can a set of internal faces be turned into two touching patches with opposite orientation?

Comment: also asked at http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-meshing/104299-how-create-zero-thickness-internal-walls-given-mesh-openfoam.html#post370085

Comment: When you write "vanishing hole" do you mean that you would like to dynamically select a set of faces within a single mesh, that should be cut out as the static cells in this tutorial? What do you need exactly?

Comment: @tomislav-maric turns out my vocabulary was missing the word baffle... in that case the solution involves calling `createBaffles` instead of `subsetMesh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `createBaffles` utility:

Use `topoSet` to create a `faceZone`, then run something like

```
createBaffles nameOfFaceZone '(nameOfMasterPatch nameOfSlavePatch)' -overwrite
```

The patches have to exist already, for which `createPatches` can come in handy.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I think the question was more one about nomenclature. The information kar was missing was the name of the utility (or that the OF-developers call the structure he wanted baffles). He seemed rather competent, so he probably already found the missing puzzle pieces at http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/search.php?searchid=1258148&pp=25

Comment: One more note: similar questions about OpenFOAM have been closed (with good reason I think) as being "too program specific for a general audience" (quoting from memory)

Comment: @GeoffOxberry I edited in a slight elaboration. #bgschaid Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Your search link is no longer valid, I found [this example](http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-meshing-technical/89141-switching-internal-faces-walls.html#post332307) though.

Comment: Concerning my edit: SE aims at providing answers that not only help the OP but also others with similar question, so I expanded your answer a bit, Concerning "similar questions", the only [closed OpenFOAM question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=[openfoam]+closed%3A1) currently existing asks for the location of a source file, which really lacks the computational science aspect. I guess my question is borderline, but as you noticed it's about nomenclature, so even users of other CFD software may find the word "baffles" alone to be a valuable pointer.

Comment: @bgschaid: OpenFOAM has a large enough user base that this sort of question seems permissible here. There are PETSc questions on this site that also ask how to accomplish certain tasks, which established the precedent for me.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry: OK. I just think that as soon as questions become too technical they should go to the MessageBoard (the community is not that big that parallel channels of communication are a good thing). Also is OpenFOAM notorious for changing usage for utilities between versions so if the questions/answers are not maintained it will diminish the value of scicomp.stackechange

Comment: @bgschaid: I encourage you to voice your concerns on Meta. I think they will spark a discussion on the role that software package questions play on SciComp.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry: OK. Did so: http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/298/when-is-a-question-answer-to-program-specific-and-what-is-the-policy-on-redirect (noticed that you answered a "symmetrical" question)

Comment: This answer is outdated you should update it.